# Namespacing patterns

Tags: javascript

After finishing this article : [Lessons From A Review Of JavaScript Code](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/27/lessons-from-a-review-of-javascript-code/)

I was wondering if my namespace

```
/**
 * The primary namespace object
 * @type {Object}
 * @alias BDDS
 */
if(!window['BDDS']) {
    window['BDDS'] = {};
}
```

if attached to the window, is this snippet invalid,
according to the following?

> Problem 9
>
> Problem: The namespacing pattern used is technically invalid.
>
> Feedback: While namespacing is implemented correctly across the rest
>   of the application, the initial check for namespace existence is
>   invalid. Here’s what you currently have: 1    if ( !MyNamespace ) { 2
>   MyNamespace = { }; 3  }
>
> The problem is that !MyNamespace will throw a ReferenceError, because
>   the MyNamespace variable was never declared. A better pattern would
>   take advantage of boolean conversion with an inner variable
>   declaration, as follows: 01   if ( !MyNamespace ) { 02      var MyNamespace
>   = { }; 03 } 04      05    //or 06 var myNamespace = myNamespace || {}; 07   08    // Although a more efficient way of doing this is: 09   //
>   myNamespace || ( myNamespace = {} ); 10   // jsPerf test:
>   http://jsperf.com/conditional-assignment 11     12    //or 13 if ( typeof
>   MyNamespace == ’undefined’ ) { 14   var MyNamespace = { }; 15 }
>
> This could, of course, be done in numerous other ways. If you’re
>   interested in reading about more namespacing patterns (as well as some
>   ideas on namespace extension), I recently wrote “Essential JavaScript
>   Namespacing Patterns.” Juriy Zaytsev also has a pretty comprehensive
>   post on namespacing patterns.

Comment: It won't throw a reference error, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No your code is correct.

`!reference` only throws a reference error if its not defined.

`window` is defined and `window["not_defined"]` just returns `undefined` for not defined variables.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a one liner but it's just a syntax thing:

```
window.SomeNamespace = SomeNamespace || {};
```